# iOS User account linked to a web account

Tags: ios, database, authentication

I am trying to create an app which is linked to user information on a website/db that I already have. So my hosted mysql database maintains username/password and other user related information and preferences. On my iphone app, I need to connect to this user database to obtain user specific information and post back more info to the database.

In essence, its somewhat like what you would find on an instagram iphone app or a tumblr app. The user can sign in from the app and have access to their existing blog/photo stream and interact with the website via the app.

Any direction on the way forward would be of immense help as I have no idea where to get started with this.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

In order to achieve what you're trying to do, you'll need to POST the username+password from the App to a script on your server, and run your SQL query to return the data back to the app. Theres an easy to use Library ASIHTTPRequest (http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) that will help you with your networking. An example below..

Example request:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourscript.php"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"user1" forKey:@"username"];
[request setPostValue:@"pass1" forKey:@"password"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Example Response:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
   NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
   NSLog(@"%@",responseString);
}
```

In your PHP Script:

```
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM users  where username='$user' and password='$pass'";

print_r($sql); //Sends response back to the App to requestFinished: method.
```

These are just brief examples, of course you should take into consideration mysql injection, and error checks. Hope this helps.

Comment: You really should require https rather than http connections and also hash the password rather than sending it outright. See: http://dustwell.com/how-to-handle-passwords.html

Comment: As I said, this is just an 'example' of how to do it in the simplest basic form to give an 'idea' of how to go about it with, no security.